# How can I Show in JS the button type when the input type "file" is not empty?

Tags: javascript, java, file, jsp

**This is the code inside my form.**

I have an external JS file that I use to Load the URL (readURL).

I would like to know how can I hide and show the Button when the file type is Empty or Not.

```
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
    <img src="<c:url value='/test/file'/>" id="newImg">
 <input type="button" id="upload" value="Load">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution for you with JS and Jquery:

```js
var imgVal = $('#file').val(); 
  if(imgVal=='') 
  { 
    $('#upload').hide();

  } 
$('#file').click(function(){
  $('#upload').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Load">
```